# Get iptc metadata of jpg image in php

Tags: php, metadata, iptc

I'm trying to get some iptc metadata from jpg image (http://pepeliana.com/images/DSC4008.jpg) with php. The Title metadata of the referenced image is set to "Testing". I've went through the php manual and both functions that seemed to do the job - iptcparse() and exif_read_data(). Both functions are enabled in php. However for the life of me, I can't figure out, why both functions do not return the desired data. Here is a sample code I've tried and I should also mention that I've also tried this code on several images that have Title iptc metadata (thus excluding the possibility of a corrupted image or improperly set metadata):

```
<?php 
$size = getimagesize ('DSC4008.jpg', $info);       
 if(is_array($info)) {   
    $iptc = iptcparse($info["APP13"]);
    foreach (array_keys($iptc) as $s) {             
        $c = count ($iptc[$s]);
        for ($i=0; $i <$c; $i++)
        {
            echo $s.' = '.$iptc[$s][$i].'<br>';
        }
    }                 
}
 ?>
```

also:

```
<?php
$exif = exif_read_data('DSC4008.jpg', 0, true);
echo $exif['WINXP']['Title'];
?>
```

As you can see, this is as simple as it gets, yet, I cannot get either to return what I want. Clearly I must be missing something obviously simple, no? Please help!

Comment: Hi I have read the php documentation php.net/manual/en/function.iptcparse.php but can you explain a) why you need to get the image size to return the array of metadata and b) the significance of the APP13 part? Also, did you get an answer to this? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have set the ImageDescription of your image to "Testing"
This here will work:

```
$exif = exif_read_data('1.jpg','IFD0',true);
echo $exif["IFD0"]["ImageDescription"];
```

echoes

```
Testing
```

Comment: this does work, thank you, however I would prefer working with iptc as it is in reality the humanly entered metadata and not metadata from the camera which is exif. I only tried exif as I could not get iptcparse to work initially. Can you/somebody comment on a solution with iptcparse?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$size = getimagesize( 'DSC4008.jpg', $iptch );

$iptc = isset( $iptch['APP13'] ) ? iptcparse( $iptch['APP13'] ) : false;
$name = isset( $iptc['2#005'] ) ? $iptc['2#005'][0] : 'Undefined';
```

Comment: Hi I have read the php documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iptcparse.php but can you explain a) why you need to get the image size to return the array of metadata and b) the significance of the APP13 part? As confused. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues and created my own [library](https://ibudasov.github.io/php7-iptc-manager/) for that

First — you'll need to install it with [Composer](https://getcomposer.org)

```
composer require ibudasov/php7-iptc-manager
```

Then

```
// import the Manager class
use iBudasov\Iptc\Manager;

// ... and instantiate it!
$manager = Manager::create();

$manager->loadFile('./DSC4008.jpg');

$title = $manager->getTag(Tag::OBJECT_NAME);
```