# How to get 'title' and 'tags' exif data from JPEG with PHP

Tags: php, metadata, exif

I have a load of JPEGs which the photographer has tagged for me. Here is one example:

[image]

How can I read the 'Title' and 'Tags' data with PHP? I have tried using `exif_read_data` but it doesn't return all of the information, this is what it returns:

```
Array
(
    [FileName] => php57F4.tmp
    [FileDateTime] => 1517222165
    [FileSize] => 10092294
    [FileType] => 2
    [MimeType] => image/jpeg
    [SectionsFound] => ANY_TAG, IFD0, THUMBNAIL, EXIF
    [COMPUTED] => Array
        (
            [html] => width="6085" height="3513"
            [Height] => 3513
            [Width] => 6085
            [IsColor] => 1
            [ByteOrderMotorola] => 0
            [ApertureFNumber] => f/1.0
            [FocusDistance] => 0.25m
            [Copyright] => 7831 262511, Copyright Retained by SG Phot
            [Copyright.Photographer] => 7831 262511
            [Copyright.Editor] => Copyright Retained by SG Phot
            [Thumbnail.FileType] => 2
            [Thumbnail.MimeType] => image/jpeg
        )

    [ImageDescription] => Ashwell- Countryside Properties
    [Make] => 
    [Model] => Hasselblad
    [Orientation] => 1
    [XResolution] => 1478517857/892159025
    [YResolution] => 25392/300
    [ResolutionUnit] => 2
    [Software] => 
    [DateTime] => (Macintosh)
    [Artist] => 22 17:40:16
    [Copyright] => 7831 262511
    [Exif_IFD_Pointer] => 12204
    [THUMBNAIL] => Array
        (
            [Compression] => 6
            [XResolution] => 72/1
            [YResolution] => 72/1
            [ResolutionUnit] => 2
            [JPEGInterchangeFormat] => 868
            [JPEGInterchangeFormatLength] => 11154
        )

    [ExposureTime] => 7/766
    [FNumber] => 0/3
    [ExposureProgram] => 1
    [ISOSpeedRatings] => 100
    [ExifVersion] => 0230
    [DateTimeOriginal] => 2018:01:16 11:20:35
    [DateTimeDigitized] => 
    [ShutterSpeedValue] => 824194609/825375280
    [ApertureValue] => 3552570/-1584963
    [ExposureBiasValue] => 1000000/8495855
    [MaxApertureValue] => 1000000/0
    [SubjectDistance] => 1/4
    [MeteringMode] => 255
    [Flash] => 0
    [FocalLength] => 1/1119
    [ColorSpace] => 65535
    [FocalPlaneXResolution] => 1000/28
    [FocalPlaneYResolution] => 1/188679
    [FocalPlaneResolutionUnit] => 3
    [FocalLengthIn35mmFilm] => 22
    [ImageUniqueID] => d
    [UndefinedTag:0xA433] => 7200000CD7
    [UndefinedTag:0xA434] => Hasselb
)
```

Comment: Maybe some more infos here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8466440/exif-title-tag-in-php-with-with-exif-read-data

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30178223/9135269

Answer (score 8):

Managed to sort it thanks to the suggestion from [Syscall](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9193372/syscall) referring me to the following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30178223/9135269

I modified it slightly, here is my finished solution:

```
function get_iptc_data( $image_path ) {
    $return = array('title' => '', 'subject' => '', 'tags' => '');
    $size = getimagesize ( $image_path, $info);

    if(is_array($info)) {
        $iptc = iptcparse($info["APP13"]);
        // var_dump($iptc); // this will show all the data retrieved but I'm only concerned with a few 
        $return['title'] = $iptc['2#005'][0];
        $return['subject'] = $iptc['2#120'][0];
        $return['tags'] = $iptc['2#025'];
    }
    return $return;
}
```

Comment: This is the only solution that works for me in getting the "title" meta!